# HTML menu title horizontal in CHROME

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello all I have a UL menu using JS and in IE the title "Filters" of the DIV is vertical and looks corrEct but in Chrome it is Horizontal

Thank you for the help

IE BROWSER
[image]

CHROME BROWSER
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="filterDiv">
<ul class="sideMenu" style="top: 280px;">
<li style="border-bottom: none;">
    <div id="filterItem" class="sideMenuDiv" ><img src="../images/plus.gif" />&nbsp;Filters</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.sideMenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.sideMenu > li {
    height: 80px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color:#000066;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px white solid;
}

div.sideMenuDiv {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    background-color:#000066;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    filter: flipv fliph;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#filterItem").click(function() {
        $("#filterPanel").fadeToggle("slow", function() {
            toggleImg( 'filter' );
        });
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        toggleImg( "filter" );
        return false;
    });
    $("#filterPanel").draggable({ snap: "#filterItem" });
});

function closeDraggablePanel( panelName, topPos)
{
    $("#"+panelName+"Panel").toggle("slow", function() {
        toggleImg( 'filter' );
        // Reposition to default
        $("#"+panelName+"Panel").css( "top", topPos);
        $("#"+panelName+"Panel").css( "left", "25");
    });

}

function toggleImg( name )
{
    if( $("#" + name +"Panel" ).is(':visible') )
    {
        $("#" + name + "Item" + " > img").attr("src", "../images/minus.gif");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#" + name + "Item" + " > img").attr("src", "../images/plus.gif");
    }
}

// Toggle the display of the element with the given ID.
function toggle(id)
{
    $('#' + id).slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [cross-browser](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/) text rotation?

Comment: It's been mentioned, but you are not using cross compatible code. Filter is only an IE thing (and likely will remain as such, as Transform seems to be taking the lead here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<span>` element around the text:

```
<div id="filterItem" class="sideMenuDiv" >
    <img src="../images/plus.gif" />&nbsp;
    <span>Filters</span>
</div>
```

And then use CSS3 Transforms:

```
div.sideMenuDiv span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);   
}
```

See the jsFiddle sample here > http://jsfiddle.net/TsUmk/.

Obviosuly you'll need to tinker around with the positioning and so forth, but this should explain a starting point for you.

Comment: That did it....thanks....What jerk voted to close this??...

Answer (score 0):

Filters are only supported in IE as of now.  It's an HTML5 thing.  The spec is not yet done, and browsers have only sporadically implemented pieces of the spec.  For instance, IE doesn't support canvas, where every other major browser does.

try using:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```